# SQL How to add parentheses to output data

Tags: sql

For a college assignment I need to show the last column of output data in parentheses as shown below.

My current query is:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1) AS '',
'.' AS '',
LastName AS '', UPPER(Title) AS '' 
FROM employees
WHERE (Title != 'Sales Representative');
```

This query shows the output as:

```
B . Brown    STOREMAN
C . Carr     RECEPTIONIST
D . Dig      DRIVER
```

I need it to show:

```
B . Brown    (STOREMAN)
C . Carr     (RECEPTIONIST)
D . Dig      (DRIVER)
```

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do this using the [CONCAT](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html) function

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1) AS '',
'.' AS'',
LastName AS '', CONCAT('(',UPPER(Title),')') AS '' 
FROM employees
WHERE (Title !='Sales Representative');
```

Comment: As a side note, is there any reason you are selecting them as blank field names?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - CONCAT worked perfectly - thank you so much.  As for the blank field names - that's how it was stated in the assignment - its not necessarily how I would make the query.

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer helped me in my solution.  For me, I guess DB2 only supports CONCAT with two arguments, so I had to call CONCAT a few times. I could not simply call CONCAT with more than two parameters. It might just be the version of DB2 I am using, but this worked below.
Try this:

```
   CONCAT(NAME, CONCAT(' (', CONCAT(UPPER(TITLE), ')'))) AS "Name and Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1) AS 'FirstName',
'.' AS'Dot',
LastName AS 'LastName', '(' + UPPER(Title) + ')' AS 'Title' 
FROM employees
WHERE (Title !='Sales Representative');
```